# Search Simultaneous Special Characters in a string using PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I am trying to work on an issue where if a string has multiple "special characters " in a string how do I replace that with a single character. 
**For Example: -**

```
$a = "INC0010347~INC0010348~~INC0010349"
$a = $a.Replace("~~","~")
$a
```

**Result 1: - "INC0010347~INC0010348~INC0010349"**

In the above case a Replace function would work if the characters are 2 in number. However anything more than 2 will fail.. as in the below:

```
$a = "INC0010347~INC0010348~~~INC0010349"
$a = $a.Replace("~~","~")
$a
```

**Result 2: - "INC0010347~INC0010348~~INC0010349"**

I am working on a script that would help me do this dynamically irrespective of the number of special characters (in this case tilde(~)) the result should be

**Result 1: - "INC0010347~INC0010348~INC0010349"**

Comment: Change the `$a.replace("~~")` to `$a -replace "~+","~"`. You should always use regex in this case. `+` is actually a greedy quantifier `+?` is the lazy one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `+` Quantifier:

```
$a = "INC0010347~INC0010348~~~INC0010349"
$a -replace '~+','~'
```

Or:

```
[regex]::Replace($a,'~+','~')
```

**Note:**

instead of using `string.Replace` method e.g. `$a.Replace('~+','~')` which will not work, use `-replace` or `[regex]::Replace` which support Regex

See:

[Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: AvShalom, Thanks for the help... Please assist me with me next question, where do you get such tips from. I know its more practice but this tip is truly good... Where can I get such Tips & Tricks